# Displaying movement tiles for a Python game

Tags: python

I am trying to create a simple tactical RPG in python, similar to Fire Emblem or Advanced Wars, but in ASCII. I have been following [this](http://www.roguebasin.com/index.php?title=Complete_Roguelike_Tutorial,_using_python%2Blibtcod) tutorial, which uses the libtcod module, and modifying the tutorial code for my own purposes

Right now I am struck trying to display movement tiles for each character. Basically I want the game to display the tiles each character can move to, whenever the user clicks his mouse over that character. I have created a function (`get_total_squares`) that generates the coordinates of the tiles to be highlighted based on the character's coordinates and movement range (hard-coded to 5, for now) and a function (`show_move_tiles`) to highlight these tiles. To record the click coordinates I have another function `target_tile` and a function to see if the coordinates match with a character's (`target_character`)

The program runs without errors, but clicking the mouse over a character does nothing (no tiles are shown).

Here is the code:

```
import libtcodpy as libtcod

#actual size of the window
SCREEN_WIDTH = 80
SCREEN_HEIGHT = 50

#size of the map
MAP_WIDTH = 80
MAP_HEIGHT = 43

LIMIT_FPS = 20  #20 frames-per-second maximum

color_dark_wall = libtcod.Color(0, 0, 50)
color_dark_ground = libtcod.Color(5, 50, 0)
color_move_tile = libtcod.Color (100, 0, 0)

class Tile:
    #a tile of the map and its properties
    def __init__(self, blocked, block_sight = None):
        self.blocked = blocked

        #by default, if a tile is blocked, it also blocks sight
        if block_sight is None: block_sight = blocked
        self.block_sight = block_sight

def target_tile():
    #return the position of a tile left-clicked, or (None,None) if right-clicked.
    global key, mouse
    while True:

        libtcod.console_flush()
        libtcod.sys_check_for_event(libtcod.EVENT_KEY_PRESS|libtcod.EVENT_MOUSE, key, mouse)
        render_all()

        (x, y) = (mouse.cx, mouse.cy)

        if mouse.rbutton_pressed or key.vk == libtcod.KEY_ESCAPE: 
            return (None, None)  #cancel if the player right-clicked or pressed Escape 

        if mouse.lbutton_pressed:
            return (x, y)
            print "works!"


def target_character():
    #Shows movement tiles if character is on click-coordinate

        (x, y) = target_tile()

        #return the first clicked character
        for obj in objects:
             if obj.x == x and obj.y == y: 
                obj.show_move_tiles()


def make_map():
    global map

    #fill map with "unblocked" tiles
    map = [[ Tile(False)
        for y in range(MAP_HEIGHT) ]
            for x in range(MAP_WIDTH) ]

    map[30][22].blocked = True
    map[30][22].block_sight = True
    map[50][22].blocked = True
    map[50][22].block_sight = True

class Object:
    #this is a generic object: the player, a monster, an item, the stairs...
    #it's always represented by a character on screen.
    def __init__(self, x, y, char, color):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.char = char
        self.color = color

    def move(self, dx, dy):
        #move by the given amount
        if not map[self.x + dx][self.y + dy].blocked:
            self.x += dx
            self.y += dy

    def draw(self):
        #set the color and then draw the character that represents this object at its position
        libtcod.console_set_default_foreground(con, self.color)
        libtcod.console_put_char(con, self.x, self.y, self.char, libtcod.BKGND_NONE)

    def show_move_tiles(self):
        global mouse
        global color_move_tile

        (x,y) = (mouse.cx, mouse.cy)

        coord_in_range = get_total_squares(5, self.x, self.y)

        for [x,y] in coord_in_range:
            if [x,y] is not [self.x, self.y]:
                libtcod.console_set_char_background(con, x, y, color_move_tile, libtcod.BKGND_SET)

    def clear(self):
        #erase the character that represents this object
        libtcod.console_put_char_ex(con, self.x, self.y, '.', libtcod.white, libtcod.black)

def handle_keys():
    #key = libtcod.console_check_for_keypress()  #real-time
    global key  #turn-based

    if key.vk == libtcod.KEY_ENTER and key.lalt:
        #Alt+Enter: toggle fullscreen
        libtcod.console_set_fullscreen(not libtcod.console_is_fullscreen())

    elif key.vk == libtcod.KEY_ESCAPE:
        return True  #exit game

def get_total_squares(dist, playerx, playery):
    coord_in_range = []
    for x in range(-dist,dist+1):
        for y in range(-dist, dist+1):
            if abs(x)+abs(y) <= dist:
                coord_in_range.append([playerx+x, playery+y])
    return coord_in_range

def render_all():
    global color_dark_wall
    global color_dark_ground

    #go through all tiles, and set their background color
    for y in range(MAP_HEIGHT):
        for x in range(MAP_WIDTH):
            wall = map[x][y].block_sight
            if wall:
                libtcod.console_put_char_ex(con, x, y, '#', libtcod.white, libtcod.black)
            else:
                libtcod.console_put_char_ex(con, x, y, '.', libtcod.white, libtcod.black)

    #draw all objects in the list and show movement if mouse hovers over player
    for item in objects:
        item.draw()
        if mouse.cx == item.x and mouse.cy == item.y:
            item.show_move_tiles()

    #blit the contents of "con" to the root console
    libtcod.console_blit(con, 0, 0, SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT, 0, 0, 0)




#############################################
# Initialization & Main Loop
#############################################


libtcod.console_set_custom_font('arial10x10.png', libtcod.FONT_TYPE_GREYSCALE | libtcod.FONT_LAYOUT_TCOD)
libtcod.console_init_root(SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT, 'python/libtcod tutorial', False)
libtcod.sys_set_fps(LIMIT_FPS)
con = libtcod.console_new(SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT)

#create object representing the player
player = Object(30, 15, '@', libtcod.white)

#create an NPC
npc = Object(SCREEN_WIDTH/2 - 5, SCREEN_HEIGHT/2, '@', libtcod.yellow)

#the list of objects with those two
objects = [npc, player]

make_map()

mouse = libtcod.Mouse()
key = libtcod.Key()

while not libtcod.console_is_window_closed():
    libtcod.sys_check_for_event(libtcod.EVENT_KEY_PRESS|libtcod.EVENT_MOUSE,key,mouse)
    #render the screen
    render_all()
    target_tile()

    libtcod.console_flush()

    #erase all objects at their old locations, before they move
    for object in objects:
        object.clear()

    #handle keys and exit game if needed
    exit = handle_keys()
    if exit:
        break
```

EDIT: I solved the previous problem of the movement tiles not showing up when I hovered the mouse over the character, but have updated the problem with a new one: trying to toggle the movement tiles on and off with a mouse click